# How can I convert these ASCI codes to Unicode?

Tags: javascript, regex, jslint

jslint appears to complain here:

```
Unexpected '\' before 'X'.
    Priv.SELECTOR = /^(@|#|\.)([\x20-\x7e]+)$/;
```

Perhaps if I used Unicode things would work?

Comment: It must be `\x20-\x7e`, you just made a typo.

Comment: @Witkor - thanks for catching the typo but how do I make this jslint friendly?  Is there a list some where of how to do this?

Comment: I had a problem with jslint when verifying template strings. I do not know how to make anything jslint friendly, or even if you should care. Well, no idea what you really can do. Try a  ``\u` notation, use `[\u0020-\u007e]`. Try a constructor - `Priv.SELECTOR = new RegExp("^([@#.])([\\u0020-\\u007e]+)$");`

Comment: Yep, it will take the \u, why did you double escape it?

Comment: Is this an ES6 feature only?

Comment: It is not ES6, it is ES5, too. It is a constructor notation, so the literal backslash is represented with a double one inside a C string literal.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `\uXXXX` notation is recognized by jslint as valid. Use

```
Priv.SELECTOR = /^([@#.])([\u0020-\u007e]+)$/;
```

or

```
Priv.SELECTOR = new RegExp("^([@#.])([\\u0020-\\u007e]+)$");
```

Note that the backslashes must be doubled inside a `RegExp` constructor.